# Marquee tag blink in browser

Tags: html, css, marquee

I have a ticker at bottom of my web page and after I open browser ticker run smooth and slowly but after a certain time it will start blinking for a couple of time and run smoothly for few seconds and does the same thing agin. Any help will be appreciated.

```
  <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left"
             style="font-size: 85px; font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-
   serif;text-transform: capitalize; margin-top: 30px;"
             onmouseover="this.stop();"
             onmouseout="this.start();">
        <div class="ticker__item__title">
            {% for key, value in collector.items %}
                {{ key }}  ${{ value|intcomma }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </marquee>
```

Comment: `The <marquee> element is obsolete and must not be used. While some browsers still support it, it's not required.` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: Before I did not use marquee, I was using javascript ticker plugin (query.webticker.js) and it was the same blinking issue so I used marquee and still occurring the same.